# requestLocationUpdates not working for Service

Tags: android, location, android-service, locationmanager, android-context

My app is using **requestLocationUpdates** (from GPS and Network, whichever comes first).

My code:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    myLocationListenerInstance);

timeout = new Timer();
timeout.schedule(myGetLastKnownLocationInstance, TIMEOUT);
```

myGetLastKnownLocationInstance is using **getLastKnownLocation**.

My problem:

When calling this code from the Activity that is currently running, the myLocationListenerInstance is getting a notification in less than TIMEOUT seconds.

However, when calling from a background Service, I'm getting timed out, and output is via last known location. The worst of it is that when investigating the Location measured, the timestamp is less than **TIMEOUT**!

Even with TIMEOUT set to a minute I'm getting this behavior.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly it works when your Activity is running, but once your Activity closes, and you expect the background service to be running, your code is not working as scheduled inside the background service.

Are you certain your background service is running?

You may need to use AlarmManager, start sticky, a wake lock, and/or startForeground to make certain the service is running when you expect your code to run.

Comment: Seems like the problem is that location updates could only be requested from the main UI thread. And apparently, in my Service, I was using some helper thread. Knowing this, I'm still stuck..

Comment: @Mugen, nope you can definitely call requestLocationUpdates from a background service.  I would read up on service lifecycle and thread handling, my guess is your service is probably starting, and then just stopping... again back to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem:
>
> When calling this code from the Activity that is currently running,
>   the myLocationListenerInstance is getting a notification in less than
>   TIMEOUT seconds.

As per [requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)), the second parameter allows you to set the *minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds*.

From the android API documentation noted above:

> The location update interval can be controlled using the minTime
>   parameter. The elapsed time between location updates will never be
>   less than minTime, although it can be more depending on the Location
>   Provider implementation and the update interval requested by other
>   applications.

You can set `minTime` (which is `0` in your case) to `TIMEOUT` and drop the `Timer` altogether, unless your timer is used elsewhere.